# Count Running and Stopped Ec2 Instances with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

How can I count number of running and stopped EC2 instances in a particular region using boto3 and an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Please be more specific on what you have tried so far or where your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that retrieves a list of instances and count the number of `stopped` and `running` instances:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    instances = [instance.state["Name"] for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all()]
    
    print('Running: ', instances.count('running'))
    print('Stopped: ', instances.count('stopped'))
```

The call to `ec2_resource.instances.all()` retrieves a list of all instances, and there is a `state` attribute that contains the `Name` of the state.

This will run in the default region for the Lambda function. If you wish to change regions, specify the region name like this:

```py
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

---

**Update:** How to be notified via SNS.

If you want to be notified via SNS, there are two options:

- Have the Lambda function directly send an SMS message to your phone via Amazon SNS using the [`publish(PhoneNumber='123')`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) command, *or*
- Have the Lambda function send a message to an Amazon SNS topic using the `publish(TopicArn=xxx)` command, and then subscribe to the SNS topic via the preferred method (eg email, SMS).

Please note that it will take a minute or so for instances to start/stop, so if you combine this with code that starts/stops instances, the count will not be accurate immediately after issuing those commands.

Comment: That script seems to work fine when i tested it but how do I get notified via SNS when this script runs? I have a lambda script that starts and stops EC2 instance and I want a lambda function to automatically count and notify me with the number of stopped and running EC2 instance whenever the stop and start lambda functions are triggered. I have created CloudWatch event with scheduled rule and SNS topic but I still don't get any notification. I have also added SNS topic as triggers in each of the lambda functions but that seems not to be working as well. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused why you would add SNS as a trigger for the Lambda function -- that seems a bit backwards since it would trigger Lambda after SNS receives a message, but it appears that you want the reverse. I've added some details to my answer.

Comment: My Question is, how do I connect this function you wrote (running & stopped state  function) to the stop and start EC2 lambda functions I have and how can I get this exact EC2 count function as an email via SNS when the EC2 stops and starts by lambda? the publish(TopicArn=xxx) did not quite work for me. I guess my poor python skills is doing me no good here. Meanwhile, cloudwatch event rules are not working for me too.

Comment: I suspect that you have many concepts mixed together, which is confusing your goal. If you have an existing Lambda function that stops and starts the instances, then you can add this code to that function. (Did you write the stop/start function yourself?) You should try to debug why `publish()` did not work -- first, manually send a message to the topic in the console to confirm that you receive an email. Then, try using the `publish()` command and see whether it gives an error message. It might be that the Lambda function has not been assigned permission to call the SNS `publish()` command.

Comment: This is the script i have that stops the ec2 instance on schedule and i also have another one that starts Ec2 on schedule as well. The script above gives the number of stopped and running instance and i want to get notified when this script below is triggered. Where do i put the publish function?                                                   import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-053']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('Instance Stopped: ' + str(instances))

Comment: You could combine the scripts together. However, as mentioned above, please note that it might take a minute or so to stop/start an instance, which will impact the numbers being reported. If you are not comfortable with 'combining' the functions, feel free to create a new Question and show us what you have attempted and what specific problem you are having.