# EC2 Instance count over time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metrics

I am looking for a way to see the number of my EC2 instances (running + stopped) over time. I tried to find it in cost explorer, cloud watch and ec2 dashboards but failed in doing so. Is that possible?

Comment: Try the `CPUUtilization` metric across all instances but choose `SampleCount` as statistic instead of average / sum / max.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @luk2302. I tried it like you said but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I just want to count the number of instances over time.

Comment: What does the graph look like in your case? Does it not display the number of instances over time? It does exactly that in my situation (maybe not the stopped instances)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406792/13126651 this can help

Comment: If you are seeking a historical count of the number of instances in each status, that probably won't come from CloudWatch. You could potentially extract the information from AWS Config, but I don't think it would be simple since you'd probably have to look at the history for each instance individually.

Comment: can give a solution using AWS CLI but not sure if it fits your requirement. The following command will return running and stoped instance count for specific region,

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped,running --output text --region <your_region> | wc -l`

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. About the python script running in lamba, it would work if I set it up now, but I won't have the historical values, so that's a pity. @JohnRotenstein I'll give that a try, since nothing until now seemed to work. vidura Thanks, but that only shows me the current value.

In any case, thank you all for the responses.